# Google AdSense on mobile device

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, ads

I want to place Google ads on my mobile app (HTML5, CSS3, jQuery mobile, Phonegap).
I thought I'd just add the same script as on my website to the HTML, but apparently there's more to it.
I was reading this: http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2472776&from=1149847&rd=1
and there it's mentioned that when creating an add I have to choose a scripting language.
Then the code is presented to me in ASP, PHP, JSP or CGI, but I want none of those, I just want to insert the regular code somehow in the HTML.
Now, what is the way to go here to get mobile ads displayed?
Any examples would be great! :)

Comment: You say Google Adwords but really you meant Google Adsense right?

Comment: @jamjam: I did indeed:) I've changed it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is "native" ie you want distribute it through an app store.

Adsense is not the answer.

You should look into [Admob](http://www.google.com/ads/admob/) (owned by Google) or [Iad](http://advertising.apple.com/) (Apple) for IOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase the post. I found a thread on inmobi website which is below. there is a vidoe tutorial to javascript integrate phonegap without plugins.
Make Money with PhoneGap & InMobi
 http://www.inmobi.com/inmobiblog/2012/02/15/make-money-with-phonegap-inmobi/ 
Thank you
Abhishek